# Meizu MX4 Ubuntu edition Fastboot problem

Tags: drivers, usb, ubuntu-touch, meizu-mx4, system-call-fastboot

My Meizu MX4 Ubuntu is stuck in a bootloop ... something is wrong with the OS image.

I can get to fastboot.
When i plug the device into windows 10 it never gets an ID.
In ubuntu i get the device recognized on certain ports with certain cables. (newer cables seem to fail).

Fastboot devices shows my device with correct serial.
lsusb shows incorrect information.:

```
Bus 001 Device 026: ID 0bb4:0c01 HTC (High Tech Computer Corp.) Dream / ADP1 / G1 / Magic / Tattoo
```

fastboot flash recovery recovery.img always gives:

```
    sending 'recovery' (11220 KB)...
FAILED (data transfer failure (Protocol error))
finished. total time: 0.575s
```

as a test i tried :

```
    username # fastboot erase recovery
< waiting for device >
erasing 'recovery'...
OKAY [  1.026s]
finished. total time: 1.026s
```

now i have no recovery and cant add one.

Can anyone please assist?

as info when i use a newer cable i get this in dmesg:

```
[  935.654637] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 31 using ehci-pci
[  935.904866] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/8, error -71
[  936.043969] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/8, error -71
[  936.218084] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 32 using ehci-pci
[  936.629555] usb 1-1.4: device not accepting address 32, error -71
[  936.701610] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 33 using ehci-pci
[  937.204994] usb 1-1.4: device not accepting address 33, error -71
[  937.277045] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 34 using ehci-pci
[  937.364966] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[  937.552774] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[  937.656674] usb 1-1-port4: unable to enumerate USB device
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like an usb connector problem to me. Maybe claiming to Meizu or trying a whole lot combination of usb cables/usb hubs/computers? I have had some of this weird behavior and still need to find some time to fully debug and claim to Meizu for the hardware if needed. Will update when I test further.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I suspect the same.

i have found on win 7 i can see the device pop up as MT65xx but with no driver.

im trying to get that to work ... will feedback if i have any success.

Phone was working fine on win 8.1 (after lots of driver issues)... The free win 10 upgrade ended the success for me.

Comment: Additionally : My phone boots to the start of the OS ... i get the ubuntu screen with the flashy dots. But then it blank screens and stops responding to screen presses. The button still lights up when touched .. but thats it.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

I failed to get fastboot working.
I downloaded flash tool for ubuntu and got a scatter image from XDA.

I was able to write the whole catter to the phone by plugging it in and holding down the volume down button.

Phone now works perfectly again.